# How to get the list of the downloaded languages in the google translate Mlkit

Tags: java, android, android-studio, language-translation, google-translator-toolkit

```
modelManager.getDownloadedModels(TranslateRemoteModel.class).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Set<TranslateRemoteModel>>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Set<TranslateRemoteModel> translateRemoteModels) {
        Log.d("TAG56565", "onSuccess: " + translateRemoteModels.toString());
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

    }
});
```

This code returns the [Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxtmN.png)

I want the list of the languages name.

If anybody knows, then please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your code/error/logs in code block instead of image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just iterate through `Set` obtained in `onSuccess` and use [`getLanguage()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/mlkit/nl/translate/TranslateRemoteModel#getLanguage()) for every item...

```
for (TranslateRemoteModel trm : translateRemoteModels) {
    Log.d("TAG56565", "onSuccess model lang:" + trm.getLanguage());
}
```